# Verify Data INSERT INTO QUERY

Tags: postgresql

Using postgresql-14 with pgadmin4
The task is vague but requests that I insert the data into a new table and then verify the data. I want to believe there is some "standard" or process to verify that the data was moved correctly and is intact, is there such a thing? I'm not sure how to "show" that the data is verified as correct in the new table.

For this insert:

```
INSERT INTO car_detail(id, make, model, price, year)
    SELECT dealership_stock.id AS id,
            manufacturers.make AS make,
            models.model_name AS model,
            price_sheet.price AS price,
            model_years.year AS year,
        FROM dealership_stock
INNER JOIN.... etc.
```

TIA - it seems like a simple and logical task, but I am baffled on how to execute and prove it.

Comment: You don't need to "verify" that an `INSERT` statement works - PostgreSQL does that for you: if it fails then it throws an error. If this `INSERT` is part of a sequence of steps then you should be using a `TRANSACTION` with a `COMMIT` a the end - but again, no "verification" is required. It sounds like you're getting program-requirements from someone who isn't qualified to micromanage you.

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with Postgres per se and more with your company's policies.  They might want to document manual operations for instance.   For example by copying and storing a select output before and after changes and storing in a secure and defined manner.  I suggest you just ask your superior if you're new to the job.

Comment: As a professional you cannot accept *The task is vague but ...*. If its vague you need to `ask questions` to those making the request or your superiors  `until you fully understand` the requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I requested a call to get the answer from the lead, but want to be sure I'm not missing something that I could learn. I will know more tomorrow after my call. Thanks again for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dai and Bjarni were correct - verification isn't required in the code. The requirement was implying that the dataset would be viewed and confirmed that the data was present in the new table. And here I had hoped to learn of some fancy new command to verify data and instead am taking Belayer's comment to heart that I need to keep asking questions until I understand the requirements! Thanks everyone!